# Pass NID to contact form

Tags: entities, emails

I have a website with a lot of furniture products.
Each node page has a link to "ask for more info" that opens the sitewide contact form. When I receive the e-mail message, I need to know to which product (node) the request refers to, because many people forget to say it. So I need to pass node url, title or nid to the form in order to insert it automatically in the sent contact e-mail.

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you using Webform for the sitewide contact form? If not, how is this set up?

Comment: the sitewide contact form, as written

Comment: Of course! I keep thinking first of contrib modules. Below is my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code, thanx to all for the help:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if($message['id'] == 'contact_page_mail') {   // is contact_page_autoreply for the sender
    if (isset($_GET['nid'])){
        $node = node_load($_GET['nid']);
        $message['body'][] = "Ref #".$_GET['nid'].": " . $node->title . " [".$node->path."]";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this link "ask for more info" needs the nid appended as query string. and then in the form this can be used.

Comment: Yes, but which hook should I use to send it via mail? How to retrieve that value, simply with $_GET["myparam"]?

Answer (score 0):

Looked at the code of the core contact module, the following line is important (contact.pages.inc:151):

```
// Send the e-mail to the recipients using the site default language.
drupal_mail('contact', 'page_mail', $to, language_default(), $values, $from);
```

By using hook_mail in your module, you could modify the body of the $message, like in the following example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function yourmodule_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  ...
  if($key == 'page_mail') {
    $nid = $_GET['mynid'];
    ...
    $message['body'][] = "Thanks for ordering the product " . $node->title;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. It works with hook_mail_alter(&$message) and if($message['id'] == 'contact_page_mail')

Answer (score 0):

Append a query string to your links (for example, /contact?nid=123). Now add the applicable field to your form (ie field_nid) - it can be hidden. In the field settings specify a default value using the token module - the format should be [current-page:query:nid] where nid is the name of the query string parameter.

Comment: Yes, I could add a hidden field, as explained here: http://willvincent.com/blog/adding-one-or-more-fields-drupal-7-contact-form, but I think it can be solved in an easier way. Thanx